# Model Training using a Data Set with CSV files and Images

Tags: dataset, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence, bar-chart, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying out to retrieve data from vertical bar charts as `x`, `y`, `x_axis_title`, `y_axis_title`. An example image is as follows.

[image: 2.png]

I am currently creating a dataset with vertical bar charts as above. with a CSV file for each image as follows.

[image: 2.csv]

1. Would it be possible to create a model that can output the titles, and values for both x, and y without using OCR(Optical character recognition) with a certain number of images?
2. Is there a specific method to build the model? or a better method?

**I was trying to do this using tesseract OCR but it was a bit inaccurate

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: My opinion is to read the file in a dict and make 2 different objects.
1 - a dict for the name of axis for the table
2 - a numpy with the content to show in table.

For drawing you can use `plotly.graph_objects`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my personal experience, Paddle OCR works a lot better than Tesseract and can help you identify all the fields. [Here](https://medium.com/@anhtuan_40207/tutorial-ocr-with-paddleocr-pp-ocr-9a4342e4d7f) is a good article explaining the usage of Paddle. Using this OCR, you will not really face any problem with the text since most of it is clearly visible

I don't think if it will be possible to get the data without that. As for the values of x and y, you can use Open CV and get intersection points of blue and white to get the points and link them with the y axis to get the exact values

Comment: Thanks for the answer, would it be possible to use ONLY the image and excel files to train a model that would be able to recognize the values of any vertical bar charts WITHOUT using OCR?

Comment: If you have the excel files then you really dont need an OCR or the image. Since all the data is present in the excel files, you can import it using pandas, and you already know the location of each entry, which you can utilise to create a general function